# How to show fragments randomly?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am creating a quiz app with Android Studio. I have an activity and PagerAdapter in it. PagerAdapter has three fragments in it. When I launch the application the fragments appear in order: fragment1, fragment2, fragment3.

I want them to appear randomly in different positions each time I launch the application. For example: fragment3, fragment1, fragment2...

The activity which has PagerAdapter in it:

```
public class testActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pager_adapter);
        initialisePaging();
    }

    private  void initialisePaging() {
        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,fragment1.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,fragment2.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,fragment3.class.getName()));
        PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_test, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

**PagerAdapter.java**

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        return this.fragments.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }

    public void setFragments(List<Fragment> fragments) {
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just shuffle the List of fragments before passing it to the adapter.

```
private  void initialisePaging() {
    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,fragment1.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,fragment2.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,fragment3.class.getName()));

    //add this line
    Collections.shuffle(fragments , new Random(System.nanoTime()));

    PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm); 
        this.fragments = fragments;
        long seed = System.nanoTime();
        //shuffle the fragment list
        Collections.shuffle(fragments , new Random(seed));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this could help but try something like this

```
Random rand = new Random();

int  n = rand.nextInt(50) + 1;
\\50 is the maximum and the 1 is our minimum
```

You can then use the int to either get/generate a name that you would like to access, maybe even put your fragments into an array and access the array by using the int(n) as an index